# How to call different URLs in parallel in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a script which basically calls certain URLs and gets the response from that request. My idea here is to see if i can call them in parallel rather than executing them sequentially.

I checked for certain ideas and saw that we can use `subprocesses` but I was not sure on how to implement the same here in my script.

My code:

```
import requests, time, zipfile, glob, os, re, json, csv
from pathlib import Path

session = requests.Session();
session.trust_env = False
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic akfjAFH131WW54='}
filecheck = Path('D:/Scripts/Projects/Input/UrlDetails.csv')
if filecheck.is_file():
    with open('D:/Scripts/Projects/Input/UrlDetails.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            env = row["Env"]
            host = row["Host"]
            port = row["Port"]
            servicepath = row["Service"]
            url = 'http://'+env+host+':'+port+'/'+service+'/check'
            r1 = session.get(url, headers=headers)
            if r1.status_code == 200:
               resp = r1.text
```

My Input file:

```
Env,Host,Port,Service,ServiceName
q1,abc.com,11316,db,SERVICE1
q1,bcd.com,11121,gw/db,SERVICE2
q1,def.com,11291,run,SERVICE3
```

Comment: You should probably use multiple threads and not subprocesses.

Comment: Have a look at [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)

Comment: Have you tried Python. Asyncio module

Comment: sure, I'll have a look at your suggestions. thanks

Comment: @AnnaRudzińska It is probably better to use `threading` (or `asyncio`) than `multiprocessing` here, since calling multiple webpages is IO bound and Python will release the GIL while waiting for the remote servers to respond.

Comment: I have read through the topics but i'm not able to figure out how to implement the logic for my particular case as i would need to call the URL based on the parameters taken from a csv file using a `for` loop